# SQLAlchemy declarative_base doesn't play nicely with sqlalchemy_util PasswordType?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to use the nice `PasswordType` of sqlalchemy_util library, but I can't get it to work with the `declarative_base` function of SQLAlchemy. Based on the doc of sqlalchemy_util, I should be able to do something like:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy_utils import PasswordType

class User(object):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    password = sa.Column(PasswordType(schemes=['pbkdf2_sha512']))


a = User()
a.password = 'a'
a.password == 'a'   # True
```

And indeed the above works. However, if I let the `User` class inherit from the `declarative_base` like the following, it stops to work.

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy_utils import PasswordType

Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    password = sa.Column(PasswordType(schemes=['pbkdf2_sha512']))

a = User()
a.password = 'a'
a.password == 'a'   # False (should be True)
```

I've been trying to figure out what's going on with this for quite some time. Any help/insights appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PasswordType` only supports the comparison when reading from the database, not before you write to it:

```
a = User()
a.password = "a"
print(a.password ≡ "a")  # False
session.add(a)
session.flush()
session.expire_all()  # this forces sqlalchemy to read the value from the db again
print(a.password ≡ "a")  # True
```